# MySQL Shutdown Unexpectedly - xampp

Tags: mysql, xampp

Hello i am facing this issue [image: image to error]
is there any fix to this

i tried using [Xampp-Fixer Tool](https://github.com/MEGAMINDMK/Xampp-Fixer), but i am afraid why does this error happens so? i am using the latest version of xampp.
is there any fix to this to not get this error again in future? every time ran into such problem i use [Xampp-Fixer Tool](https://github.com/MEGAMINDMK/Xampp-Fixer) to fix my issue all the time but im tired of this error, let me know if theres a legal fix thanks

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow megamind, have you checked that there are no port in conflict with mysql? have you checked windows event viewer?

Comment: no ports confliction

Comment: the script that you made, [`mariabackup`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/full-backup-and-restore-with-mariabackup/) did similar steps (take backup the `data` folder and restore using `backup` folder) with extra such as but not limited to backup verification, incremental backup, and consistency check. but, the thing is, if you need such kind backup, you might be abusing the xampp's mariadb. tbh, i want to know your habit using xampp - did you turn it off properly or just kill it using task manager. please do check `windows event viewer` to make sure we got all the info.

Comment: No actually the thing is power failure, the system runs woth no ossues but there is sometimes power failiure due to which i suppose system it self and xampp obviously doesnt get closed properly due to which it might get crash at points or something

Comment: ah i see, then it might be the cause of the problem. if having an UPS (Uninterruptible Power Supply) is out of question, you would be hard pressed to deal with that issue everytime it happens..

Comment: then i suppose it leaves me to use my tool right